# How to get Enum's rawValue based on it's attribute value - Swift

Tags: swift, enums

This is my Enum:

```
enum Object: Int{

    case House1 = 0
    case House2 = 1

    var descriptor:String{
        switch self{
        case .House1: return "Cottage"
        case .House2: return "House"
        }
    }
}
```

I want to know is there a way to get `rawValue` returned if I provide value of descriptor?

For example, I want to know Enum value if my String is "Cottage"
(It should return 0)

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create an initialiser for your enum that takes the descriptor and returns the enum value for it, then just call `enumValue.rawValue`. See the following:

```
enum Object: Int{

    case House1 = 0
    case House2 = 1

    var descriptor:String{
        switch self{
        case .House1: return "Cottage"
        case .House2: return "House"
        }
    }

    init(descriptor: String) {
        switch descriptor {
            case "Cottage": self = .House1
            case "House": self = .House2
            default: self = .House1 // Default this to whatever you want
        }
    }
}
```

Now do something like `let rawVal = Object(descriptor: "House").rawValue`

Comment: That's exactly what I needed

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you've designed your object incorrectly for your own needs. If that was the sort of thing you wanted to do, why didn't you make the raw value a string?

```
enum Object: String {
    case House1 = "Cottage"
    case House2 = "House"
}
```

Now what you're asking for just works, right out of the box.

If there is some other reason why you need House1 to correspond to both `0` and `"Cottage"`, tell us what it is. But so far, from what you've said, it sounds like what you want is not an enum at all. Perhaps a simple array would have been better:

```
["Cottage", "House"]
```

That gives you direct two-way interchange between `0` and `"Cottage"` (i.e. the index number).

Answer (score 0):

```
enum Object: Int{

    case House1 = 0
    case House2 = 1

    var description: String {
        return descriptor
    }

    var descriptor:String{
        switch self{
        case .House1: return "Cottage"
        case .House2: return "House"
        }
    }

    static func valueFor(string:String) -> Int{
        switch string{
        case "Cottage": return 0
        case "House": return 1
        default: return 2
        }
    }
}


let obj = Object.House1

print(obj.description)
print(obj.rawValue)
print(Object.valueFor(string: "Cottage")

//Output
Cottage
0
0
```